# Found XSS in chat form in bug bounty but they say it's only self XSS. How to leverage it?

Tags: xss, self-xss

I have found an XSS bug in a chat form on a bug bounty target. When I enter in the chat form input `<button onclick="alert(1)">click</button>` and after that I click the button a popup alert appears. I`ve sent the bug but they said:

> Thank you for your submission. However, based on the current
> circumstances this finding qualifies only as a Self-XSS! Could you
> elaborate this and provide us with more reproduction steps on how we
> could take leverage of this finding and use this against other
> Users/Victims?
>
> For now, I am lowering this to the P5/Informational variant but do let
> us know If you can escalate this further.

How can I escalate this further?

Comment: Is the XSS reflected (off the server) or DOM-based (client-side only)? If reflected, can you trigger the request from another site (via URL GET parameters or HTML form POST body)? Self-XSS can be a way to turn CSRF into XSS (which is more powerful than CSRF). Is the message that you input (with the payload) stored and displayed anywhere else (as a message to another person, or a log), and if so, can it trigger the XSS there too? Is your view of the vulnerable page one you can send other (authenticated) users to without making them sign in as you first?

Comment: Clearly this question displays some understanding - it talks about XSS, mentions a specific payload, etc. Perhaps it should be closed for some other reason, but not the one currently selected.

Comment: Have you tried other payloads or other event-handlers so far?

Comment: @Anders It needs more information, so I am voting to leave it as closed for now until OP provides more info.

Answer (score 2):

There are two "improvements" I can see here.

First, target the person you are chatting with, not yourself. Can you start a chat with yourself on different devices? Send the attack from device A, and see if it can be executed on device B. If this is more like a customer support chat, where users don't chat with other users, this may be tricky. If you can't see the application from the perspective of the person receiving your attack message, you can't really know if it is executed or not.

Second, make the attack execute without any user interaction. An onerror is one way to do this:

```
<img src="doesnotexistatall.com/" onerror="alert('xss')">
```

However, without adressing the first point it will still just be self-XSS.